# How to Display next and previous records on clicking on next and previous button in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jbutton

```
private void cmd_nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     

  pst=conn.prepareStatement("select * from questions where subject= ?");
            pst.setString(1, "websites");
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
   while(rs.next())
            {

                 qs=rs.getString("question");
                 option1=rs.getString("option1");
                 option2=rs.getString("option2");
                 option3=rs.getString("option3");
                 txt_quest.setText(qs);
                jcb_opt1.setText(option1);
                jcb_opt2.setText(option2);
                jcb_opt3.setText(option3);

       }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
            }
```

I want to get the next row from the table on clicking the `next` button and previous row on clicking the `previous` button. Is there any easy way to do so...?

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to use `CardLayout`.

Comment: You're best bet is to unload all the rows into a data structure like a list. You then keep an index to the current option. When you click next, increment the index. When you click previous, decrement the index. Always show the option at the current index.

Comment: can u plz give me a demo

Comment: Your `Resultset rs` already contains all the rows with questions on a given subject.  It gas `next()` and `previous()` methods. Additionally it has `isFirst()` and `isLast()` methods, that you might not even need..  So you have all the tools to create the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should not "**select * from questions**" in a method, where you just want to get rs.next(). If you want to get rs.previous() would you "select *" again? 
Place your select at the beginning  of your program.

There are three cases you need to consider for a well designed **cmd_nextActionPerformed**:

1. Your DB-table is empty, or has only one entry. In this case next-button should be disabled,  since there is no next entry.
2. You have a next entry. Get the data and refresh the JTextFields. Next-button should be enabled.
3. You are at the end. After rs.next() check and if rs.isAfterLast() returns true, then you need to go to rs.last() and stay there. Next-button should be disabled.

The good news is that **cmd_previousActionPerformed** is symmetrical.

Comment: can u tell me how to use increment in rows to get the next row automatially...?

Comment: rs.next() does that automatically. Check the 3 aspects regarding location and size of your result-set.

Answer (score 0):

for next,

```
rs.next()
```

for previous,

```
rs.previous();
```